# Best way to prevent direct calls to a microservice hosted in a docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, microservices

I have a simple, proof of concept system that has 2 APIs:  one act as the gateway and the other is a microservice.  I have created docker containers for both and run them together using a docker compose file.

Everything work well, except I am not sure how to restrict the microservice from being called directly.

Here is my compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  apigateway:
    image: apigateway
    container_name: api-gateway
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: api_gateway/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 7500:7500
    networks:
      - api-local

  apiadmin:
    image: apiadmin
    container_name: api-admin
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: api_admin/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 7501:7501
    networks:
      - api-local

networks:
  api-local:
    external: true
```

I can call localhost:7500/some_url and I get back a response.  I can also call localhost:7501/some_url and I also get a response.  However, I want to prevent clients from calling the 7501 microservice directly.  I want all traffic to go through the gateway only.

I can filter the IP in the microservice and reject the connection if not from the gateway IP, but I was wondering if there better approach.

Comment: don't publish the ports. Container in the same network are able to communicate without published ports. If they are not in the same network, then it even gets problematic with published ports, since the notion of localhost is by default not sufficient. Each container is its own localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try not to expose the microservice port to the host in your docker-compose file, it should be still reachable within the docker network and accessible to the gateway:

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  apigateway:
    image: apigateway
    container_name: api-gateway
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: api_gateway/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 7500:7500
    networks:
      - api-local

  apiadmin:
    image: apiadmin
    container_name: api-admin
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: api_admin/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - api-local

networks:
  api-local:
    external: true
```

Please, note I removed the port mapping for the `apiadmin` service.